# Updating both tables in an inner join produces a strange rows matched count

Tags: mysql

I had updated a contact table joined with a company table using the following SQL:

```
UPDATE contact join company on contact.FK_Company = company.PK_Company
SET contact.Mailer = 'PeriodicNews',
    contact.Mailer_Date = '2018-04-23'
WHERE
   NOT contact.Unsubscribe
   AND NOT contact.Bounced
   AND NOT contact.Spam_Filter
   AND (contact.Primary_E_Mail LIKE '%@yahoo.com'
          OR contact.Primary_E_Mail LIKE '%@aol.com')
   AND contact.SPM_Contact
   AND company.Customer
   AND company.Business_State in ('ME', 'VT', 'NH', 'MA', 'RI', 'CT', 'NY', 'NJ', 'PA','DE', 'MD')
;
```

If I rerun the SQL under the MySQL Console, the number of rows changed is reported (naturally) as 0 and the number of rows matched as 112. If I now add what I think is an innocuous addition to set the company.Customer column to itself, as in:

```
UPDATE contact join company on contact.FK_Company = company.PK_Company
SET contact.Mailer = 'PeriodicNews',
    contact.Mailer_Date = '2018-04-23',
    company.Customer = company.Customer /*** This is the new line ! ***/
WHERE
   NOT contact.Unsubscribe
   AND NOT contact.Bounced
   AND NOT contact.Spam_Filter
   AND (contact.Primary_E_Mail LIKE '%@yahoo.com'
          OR contact.Primary_E_Mail LIKE '%@aol.com')
   AND contact.SPM_Contact
   AND company.Customer
   AND company.Business_State in ('ME', 'VT', 'NH', 'MA', 'RI', 'CT', 'NY', 'NJ', 'PA','DE', 'MD')
;
```

Now, as before, the number of rows changed is still 0 but the number of rows matched is reported as 192. I can't figure out why an additional 80 rows have been matched when there are only 112 rows that satisfy the WHERE conditions. If I remove the "AND company.Customer" condition, then there are still only 131 rows that match.

Comment: Perhaps because now you're also updating the Company table, so rows from that table are now also matched. Do the numbers add up?

Comment: And what would those two numbers be?